# Why do I get different frequencies depending of the time I apply group_by() and distinct() in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am quite new to R and the tidyverse, and I can't wrap my head around the following:

Why do I get a different frequencies depending on when I `group_by()` and `distinct()` my data?

[image: Different user frequencies depending on when distict and group_by are applied]

```
output_df_1 <- input_df %>%
  mutate(created_at = lubridate::floor_date(created_at, unit = "hours")) %>%
  select(created_at, author_id) %>%
  arrange(created_at) %>%
  distinct(author_id, .keep_all = T) %>%
  group_by(created_at) %>%
  count(created_at)

output_df_2 <- input_df %>%
  mutate(created_at = lubridate::floor_date(created_at, unit = "hours")) %>%
  select(created_at, author_id) %>%
  arrange(created_at) %>%
  group_by(created_at) %>%
  distinct(author_id, .keep_all = T) %>%
  count(created_at)

full_join(output_df_1 , output_df_2 , by = "created_at") %>%
  rename(output_df_1 = n.x,
         output_df_2 = n.y) %>%
  melt(id = "created_at") %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x=created_at, y=value, colour=variable),
            linetype = "solid",
            size = 0.75) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#005293","#E37222"))
```

**Context**

input_df is a dataframe containing observations of tweets with timestamps and author_ids. I would like to produce a plot with variable1 being tweets per hour (this poses no problem) and variable2 being distict users per hour. I am not sure which of the two lines in the above plot correcly visualizes the distinct users per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is because in the first code, you use `distinct` before `group_by` and `count`.
2. Morover it is the use of `group_by`. `count` automatically also groups:
   `count` is same as `group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(freq=n())`.

Here is an example:

```
mtcars %>% 
  distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  count(cyl)

mtcars %>% 
  distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE) %>% 
  count(cyl)
```

gives:

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
+   count(cyl)
  cyl n
1   6 2
> mtcars %>% 
+   distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE) %>% 
+   count(cyl)
  cyl n
1   6 2
```

If you change the order of `distinct`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE) %>% 
  count(cyl)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE)
```

you get:

```
 mtcars %>% 
+   distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE) %>% 
+   count(cyl)
  cyl n
1   6 2
> 
> mtcars %>% 
+   count(cyl) %>% 
+   distinct(am, .keep_all=TRUE)
Error: `distinct()` must use existing variables.
x `am` not found in `.data`.
```

In your example, this code should give the same result for `df1` and `df2`:

```
output_df_1 <- input_df %>%
  mutate(created_at = lubridate::floor_date(created_at, unit = "hours")) %>%
  select(created_at, author_id) %>%
  arrange(created_at) %>%
  distinct(author_id, .keep_all = T) %>%
  count(created_at)



output_df_2 <- input_df %>%
  mutate(created_at = lubridate::floor_date(created_at, unit = "hours")) %>%
  select(created_at, author_id) %>%
  arrange(created_at) %>%
  distinct(author_id, .keep_all = T) %>%
  count(created_at)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination! Just so I understood correctly:
Basically my ´output_df_1´ would be correct for my context, as it firsts distincts and then counts. I just need to modify my code by removing the ´group_by´ as it is redundant because it is included in the ´count´ function?

Comment: Yes. I updated the code at the end for both `df1` and `df2`.